# Get the list of due assignments using Google Classroom API

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-classroom

I am trying to get the list of assignments due/coursework for all the courses using the `Google Classroom API`. I am getting a list of courses using the below code :

```
results = service.courses().list(pageSize = 10).execute()
courses = results.get('courses',[])
```

Once I get the list of all the courses, I loop over each the course and try to supply the `courseID` in order to get the list of coursework using `courses.courseWork.list` method, but I'm getting an error.

I have written the following code :

```
for course in courses :
    print(course['name'])
    print "Assignments you have due in this course : "
    print course[u'id']
    course_work_results = service.courses().courseWork().list().execute()
    print course_work_results
```

Since I am not supplying the `courseID` anywhere (which I need to know how to do), I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "classroom.py", line 53, in <module>
  course_work_results = service.courses().courseWork().list().execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 727, in method
  raise TypeError('Missing required parameter "%s"' % name)
TypeError: Missing required parameter "courseId"
```

The error is caused due to the line

```
course_work_results = service.courses().courseWork().list().execute()
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-courses#retrieve_course_details

Comment: Yeah...nothing clear is mentioned on how to use courseWork.list() there. @jonrsharpe

Comment: But it shows you how to get a course by ID, which is what you were asking.

Comment: I have already done that part, once I get the ID, I need to pass it as an argument to get the courseWork for that course, which I don't know how to do. @jonrsharpe

Comment: Presumably with `.courseWork().list(courseId=course[u'id'])`. There is also a page on managing coursework: https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-coursework, and all of the endpoints follow the same patterns.

Comment: Yeah, I did that but this error shows up now : `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/4191567678/courseWork?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">
` @jonrsharpe

Comment: Well then you need to authenticate, also covered in the documentation. If you're already authenticated you'll probably need to talk to an admin about your permissions.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is that in the .list() parenthesis you add `courseId={the course id}` as a parameter. For the authentication error, you just need to add the scope 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me' to your scopes list, delete your token file, and run the program and authenticate again with the new scopes. Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).